# ERROR in visual studio (C#) : No Overload method 'UpdateStudentData' takes 1 arguments

Tags: c#

1.I am VERY new to C# and visual studio as a new student programmer, I have a student database in Access and connects to my project in visual studio. The connection string have been set up. and it works as my login screen verifies data in DB once I am in my form to save data I get an error "No overload for method 'updateStudentData' takes 1 arguments. it point to Form.CS file in the line but it appears to be correct, I assume I have to do with when I set up my query within visual studio. I am stumped. Please advise in what I should look at, thank you all in advance!

2.the error point to this segment of code where asterisks are:

private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

{

try

{

```
studentBindingSource.EndEdit();
**studentTableAdapter.UpdateStudentData(this.k5smsData.Student);**
panel1.Enabled = false;
```

}

Answer (score 2):

You are attempting to call the `UpdateStudentData` method with a single input (`this.k5smsData.Student`). The error is telling you that the `UpdateStudentData` method exists, but it is not defined in a way that you can pass just one input (argument) to it.

You need to figure out what (if any) parameters the `UpdateStudentData` method accepts and call it accordingly. Place your cursor inside the parentheses on the line indicating the error and from the Visual Studio menu choose "Edit" -> "IntelliSense" -> "Parameter Info". A small pop-up should appear near your cursor with information about what parameters the method will accept.

It's quite possible that there is more than one version of the `UpdateStudentData` method and each one will accept different parameters. In that case you can cycle through the parameter sets with the up and down arrows on your keyboard.

Comment: Thank you so much there was more than one bindingsource, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

With the amount of code you have provided it is not very easy to help you. However, the error message is pretty clear. Check the signature of the method in `UpdateStudentData` and you should be able why you don't match it.